# reticulate ImportError: No module named pandas in Rstudio version 1.2

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I am trying to use the reticulate package in a Rmd file. I first created a setup chunk as follows:

```
library(reticulate)
use_virtualenv("r-reticulate")
use_python("C:\\Python27")
```

Then I import `pandas`:

```
#importing libraries
import pandas
```

```
 ImportError: No module named pandas

Detailed traceback: 
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
```

I have checked that pandas is already installed from the python command line. Why am I getting an import error here?

Comment: Silly question, but did you install `pandas` while the virtualenv was active?

Comment: @CodeSpent thanks for your comment. I guess I updated it to make sure that it was installed. Was that the culprit? What should I do now?

Comment: Well your virtualenv is isolating your application, so just `pip install pandas` from inside your virtualenv.

Comment: Where do I do `pip install pandas`? Python does not recognize that. I can only do that in cmd on Windows and I am not sure if there is a cmd engine in knitr. Sorry, I am an R user and still learning Python.

Comment: Added an answer, let me know if that works or if you need some more clarification. :)

Answer (score 21):

install the package in R using the py_install()

```
library(reticulate)
py_install("pandas")
```

refer this -> https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/python_packages.html

Answer (score 3):

Solved.
For /usr/bin/python3 pandas was available,
but not for /usr/local/bin/python3

In RStudio, Tools/Global options...
Halfway down is Python. Set the interpreter to /usr/bin/python3
After restarting R,
import pandas
now works.

Comment: I had the same problem and this did it.  Had to point it to my local installation of Python.

Answer (score 1):

It appears `pandas` is not installed in your virtualenv. It may be on your machine, but your virtualenv isolates your application from the rest of your machine.

**While your virtualenv is active:**

- Open cmd/bash
- Run `pip install pandas`

Now `pandas` should be available to you within this `env`. [Later you can generate a `requirements.txt` file](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/better-python-dependency-and-package-management-b5d8ea29dff1) that makes dependency management much easier.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however, this didn't work for me. I first did `library(reticulate)
use_virtualenv("r-reticulate")
use_python("C:\\Python27")`. Then `pip install pandas` in cmd showed that requirement is already satisfied. Then I ran the `python` chunk `import pandas`. However, I still get `ImportError: No module named pandas`. I have also tried closing and re-opening rstudio but to no avail.

Comment: What about trying `py_install("pandas")`?

Comment: `NameError: name 'py_install' is not defined`

Comment: Hmm. According to [this article](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reticulate/vignettes/python_packages.html) that's the proper way of installing python packages.

Comment: I've tried all the options and somehow managed to fail everytime! Gonna watch youtube videos on reticulate now. Thanks for your help @CodeSpent

Comment: Good luck, I'm sorry I don't really use RStudio so can't be too much help. Is RStudio a necessary prerequisite? It sounds like its going to make things a bit more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Yes, the preview version of RStudio is a requirement to use reticulate. However, I've abandoned it for now and I'm using the plain `python` engine in `rmarkdown`. That's working for me.

Comment: @umairdurrani did the ```python``` engine in ```rmarkdown``` worked for you? I am trying to install package ```ortools``` and it is throwing me some error.

Comment: @Shibaprasadb Yes. Both `reticulate` and python engine in `rmarkdown` work for me.